# Dart - List.generate with Future

Tags: json, flutter, dart

So I have the following problem:
I have created this class which fetches a JSON from the internet which is formatted like:

```json
{"id":0,"name":"McMonalds","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed congue laoreet nibh, id sollicitudin diam efficitur id. ","cuisines":"02,03,04,05","logo":"http:\/\/example.com\/assets\/logo.png","images":"http:example.com\/assets\/image1.png,http:example.com\/assets\/image2.png,http:example.com\/assets\/image3.png","color":15381263}
```

so now my problem is that I have to use this class like this:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Restaurant {
  const Restaurant(this.name, this.id, this.description, this.cuisines,
      this.color, this.logo, this.images);
  final String name;
  final String id;
  final String description;
  final List<int> cuisines;
  final Color color;
  final Image logo;
  final List<Image> images;
  static Future<Restaurant> fetchRestaurant(String id, bool repeat) async {
    final response =
        await http.get("http://example.com/getRestaurant.php?id=" + id);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Restaurant.fromJson(response.body);
    } else {
      if (repeat) {
        Restaurant.fetchRestaurant(id, false);
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load Restaurant');
      }
    }
  }

  factory Restaurant.fromJson(String decode) {
    Map data = json.decode(decode) as Map;
    return (Restaurant(data["name"].toString(), data["id"].toString(), data["description"].toString(), data["cuisines"].toString().split(",").map(int.parse).toList(), Color(data["color"] as int), Image.network(data["logo"].toString()), List<Image>.generate(data["images"].toString().split(",").length, (index) => Image.network(data["images"].toString().split(",")[index]))));
  }
}
```

but I have to use it like this:

```dart
List<Restaurant> restaurants = List<Restaurant>.generate(
        10, (index) => (Restaurant.fetchRestaurant("0", true)));
```

Does anyone know how to get around this, been looking for solutions forever now but could not find anything useful

If you need any further information don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Try take a look at `Future.wait`: `List<Restaurant> restaurants = await Future.wait(Iterable.generate(10, (index) => Restaurant.fetchRestaurant("0", true)));` https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.1/dart-async/Future/wait.html

Comment: Or an shorter alternative: `List<Restaurant> restaurants = [for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) await Restaurant.fetchRestaurant("0", true)];`

Comment: It might make this situation simpler to do away with the idea of creating a list of `Restaurant` in the first place. Depending on what you need the list for, it would probably be a more desirable approach to create a list of restaurant-related widgets and have each widget responsible for fetching it's own `Restaurant`.